# Putting a greenscreened actor over a 3D model

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, effects

I already have all of the tracking and keyframing and stuff done using the tools in blender, and I know you can add a 3D object into your video by clicking the "Set as Background" button in the movie clip editor. However, I want to add my now keyframed video *over* a 3D object. I initially thought I could just route the information from the tracked blender camera to the vse and layer it there, but I couldn't see an obvious way to do this, and I wan't able to find anything like this online. I also tried rendering the video and then importing the render to the vse or some other program, but the rendered video is just the original real video with the green screen a not-so-green color due to the keying.

Comment: [Keying](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/matte/index.html#matte-nodes) is done in the compositor as well as alpha over operations.

Comment: I've done my keying in the compositor, my question is how to get the composite output from the compositor into the vse.

Comment: Add a 'scene' strip with overdrop and convert the alpha in the compositor to premultiplied